# Reading dangerously large protocol message Caffe warning

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

I am trying to fine tune the fully convolutional nets for my problem. I am getting the following warning. 
Why I am getting this warning?

```
     [libprotobuf WARNING google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc:505] Reading dangerously 
     large protocol message.  If the message turns out to be larger than 2147483647 bytes, 
     parsing will be halted for security reasons.  To increase the limit (or to disable 
     these warnings), see CodedInputStream::SetTotalBytesLimit() in google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h.
```

Comment: I think you need not worry too much about it. You are getting that warning because your model proto might be close to `2147483647` bytes.

Comment: ya, I get this all the time...never affects my nets.  If it bothers you, change the source code before compiling.  Although I'm sure the warning is there for some reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2147483647 is the max value that you can store in an integer data type in C++.

Caffe reads the .prototxt file into a buffer and then reads the parameters from the buffer. This buffer is defined internally to be of a maximum size of 2147483647 bytes. So if the .prototxt file is too large, it may not fit into this buffer. So Caffe gives this warning to increase the limit.

Comment: Will it automatically resize after the warning?

Comment: No. You have to do it. See CodedInputStream::SetTotalBytesLimit() in google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h.